# How to use Google Cloud Storage in a Django app hosted on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: django, filesystems, storage, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am using **Django 1.7, Gunicorn and Nginx** for my app. It is hosted on **GCE VM instance**.

I want to store all my user uploaded content in **Google Cloud Storage,** so that it is easily accessible in case the traffic increases and I have to use *multiple VM instances* behind a HTTP/Network load balancer.

Given that Google does not allow attaching a storage disk to multiple VM instances in write mode, Google Cloud Storage looks like the only option. I want to use Google Cloud Storage as a file system or something similar to that.

Please let me know if there are any other options.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use the [Google Cloud Storage Python Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) from your Django app to access GCS.

See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26914885/3618671) for a list of alternatives (the original question was about persistent disk, so GCS is one of the options, as you have already discovered):

> If you want to share data between them, you need to use something other than Persistent Disk, e.g., Google's [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/), [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), or [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/), or you can run your own database (whether SQL or NoSQL), a distributed filesystem (Ceph, Gluster), or a file server ([NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html), [SAMBA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!)), among other options.