# Attaching a disk to multiple GCE instances with one write access

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm thinking about upgrading my company's integration server with a the repos on a separate disk that would be shared with a backup server. Like so:

[Main Integration Server] ---R/W--- [Repo Vdisk] ---R/O--- [Backup Integration Server]

My problem is that according to the GCE docs, if I attach the same Vdisk to more than one instance, all instances must only access the disk in read-only mode. What I'm looking to do would be to have one instance access it in read-write, and one in read-only mode.

Is this at all possible without powering up a third instance to act as a sort of "storage server"?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910960/share-persistent-disk-with-other-compute-engine

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think of using the word "sharing" in my searches...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you quoted from the docs and as mentioned in my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26914885/3618671), if you attach a single persistent disk to multiple instances, they must all mount it in read-only mode.

Since you're looking for a fully-managed storage alternative so you don't have to run and manage another VM yourself, consider using Google Cloud Storage and mount your bucket with [gcsfuse](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse) which will make it look like a regular mounted filesystem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out gcsfuse - I looked into using that myself, but I came to the conclusion that the traffic to our repo would become prohibitively expensive if using GCS, not to mention performance issues when commits are written out.

Comment: @ZalánMeggyesi What about using [`sshfs`](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) with a single VM acting as central data storage node, and others mounting it via FUSE SSH? Or maybe you want to use NFS or SAMBA instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a shared filesystem you can't read and write from multiple VMs to a single disk, regardless of what Persistent Disk (PD) supports. The use case for a PD with read-only attachments is for sharing of static content; check a [blog](https://www.beginswithdata.com/2023/11/20/google-cloud-read-only-disk/) I wrote for more on those use cases.

In your situation you need shared storage could look into:

- Managed options:

  - [Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/overview) using NFS
  - [Google Cloud NetApp Volumes](https://cloud.google.com/netapp/volumes/docs/discover/overview) using NFS or SMB
- Self-managed options:

  - Build yoruself NFS or SMB server. If you have a very large content repository to share build your own storage server with using [Hyperdisk Throughput](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/hyperdisks) storage and dial down the provisioned MiBs for a very cost effective solution

[GCSFuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) was also mentioned in the comments but I don't think it is suitable for the question asked; it's optimized for read workloads of multi MB size files and not a general purpose read/write workload.