# Google Compute Engine - shared disk

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm wondering if possible to create a shared disk, between Google Compute Engine Virtual Machines?

For example, create 10 VMs, that shared information via this disk. Every VM can read/write into it on different file, without disturbing each other.

I'm read about Persistent Disk, but I'm not sure that this allows me to attach multiple VMs with one disk.

If the answer is yes, few more questions:

1. What are the expected performance?
2. This method also support SSD HD?
3. What is the max disk capacity?
4. What is the max number of clients (VMs) that can be attached to same disk?
5. What is the pricing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share persistent disk with other compute engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910960/share-persistent-disk-with-other-compute-engine)

Answer (score 4):

You may mount a persistent disk onto multiple VMs simultaneously, but only when that disk is solely in read-only mode.

For more: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#use_multi_instances