# How do I get access to a Google Compute VM Filesystem remotely using the Java API?

Tags: java, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm building a framework application for managing files between compute engines based on their roles. I've been able to find a lot of information for managing the compute engines themselves, but nothing for getting access to them to manage files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Google API for reading and writing to instance filesystems from outside the instance. You will need to run a service on the instance (ftp, sftp, whatever) if you want external access to its filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Fratzke, first of all your question is incomplete, what platform are you using on compute engine instances, do you want only read only access ?

Note if you want a persistence disk to be shared among many compute engine instances, you can do that only in read only mode. The google documentation clearly states that :

> It is possible to attach a persistent disk to more than one instance. However, if you attach a persistent disk to multiple instances, all instances must attach the persistent disk in read-only mode. It is not possible to attach the persistent disk to multiple instances in read-write mode.

However, you can share files between multiple instances using the managed services like [google cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), [google cloud datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/) etc. Answer for similar question is already on SO. Refer this links:

[Share a persistent disk between Google Compute Engine VMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910960/share-a-persistent-disk-between-google-compute-engine-vms)

Edit:
If you want to access a filesystem on a multiple instances remotely using JAVA, then they have to make filesystem available with a service. Such a service is typically a background job, which handles incoming requests and returns a response, e.g. for authentication, authorization, reading and writing. The specification of the request/response pattern is called a protocol - e.g. NFS on UNIX/LINUX. U cn write ur own file service provider & run it on the instnces. As transport layer for such an endeavor sockets (TCP/IP) can be used. good transport layer would be the http protocol, e.g. with a restful service.

Edit - 2

Nother possibility is using [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs), mount the filesystem on each instance and use them within your java code as mounted network shared drive.

Hope this helps you ...Warm Regards.

Comment: None of what you posted has anything to do with what I asked. I have multiple VM instances in google compute, each has their own respective disk and their own respective filesystem. I want to connect to that filesystem on their respective machine so I can manage (See Read-Write) the files on them using the java api.

Comment: There is no API for reading and writing to instance filesystems from outside the instance. You will need to run a service on the instance (ftp, sftp, whatever) if you want external access to its filesystem.

Comment: If you want to access a filesystem on a multiple instances, then they have to make filesystem available with a service. Such a service is typically a background job, which handles incoming requests and returns a response, e.g. for authentication, authorization, reading and writing. The specification of the request/response pattern is called a protocol -  e.g. NFS on UNIX/LINUX. U cn write ur own file service provider & run it on the instnces. As transport layer for such an endeavor sockets (TCP/IP) can be used.  good transport layer would be the http protocol, e.g. with a restful service

Comment: Nother possibility is using [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs), mount the filesystem on each instance and use them within your java code as mounted network shared drive.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg Can you put that in an answer and I'll approve? That's exactly what I needed to know. Thank you.