# What is the correct way to add a second disk using Terraform on Google Compute

Tags: google-compute-engine, terraform

I am trying to add a second disk to a Google Compute instance using Terraform.  This seems to be correct:

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "seconddisk" {
    name  = "seconddisk"
    type  = "pd-standard"
    zone  = "us-west1-a"
    size = "100"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "someinstance" {

    name         = "someinstance"
    machine_type = "n1-standard-4"
    zone         = "us-west1-a" 

    disk {
        image = "${var.image_url}"
    }

    disk {
        disk = "${google_compute_disk.seconddisk.name}"
    }

    ...
}
```

However, I get the following error:

google_compute_instance.kafka1: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 409: The resource '...' already exists, alreadyExists.

Thoughts?

Comment: That should work fine for attaching mulitple disks to an instance: https://gist.github.com/ryane/392c1565d83c63df851d1be36b2f4a8a

It looks like you are running into a different problem. Perhaps you have an unexpected instance leftover in your account that is causing a conflict?

Comment: It may just a timing issue.  I added a depends on flag and it seems to work, but it still fails occasionally.  I was thinking there was something I was missing or leaving out.

Comment: is there a way to mount a disk in R/W across multiple VMs?

Comment: @mike.bukosky https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910960/share-a-persistent-disk-between-google-compute-engine-vms

Answer (score 3):

As of 2022 May, you can do following

```
# disk
resource "google_compute_disk" "default" {
  name = "compute-disk"
}

# compute
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "attached-disk-instance"
  machine_type = "e2-medium"
  zone         = "us-west1-a"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }
  network_interface {
    network = "default"
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [attached_disk]
  }
}

# connect compute & disk
resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "default" {
  disk     = google_compute_disk.default.id
  instance = google_compute_instance.default.id
}
```

Helpful resources

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_attached_disk
- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance
- https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-docs-samples