# K8s PersistentVolume - smart way to view data

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Using Google Cloud & Kubernetes engine:

Is there a smart way to view or mount a 
PersistentVolume(physical Storage, in the case of Google PD) to a local drive/remote computer/macos, or anything able to view data on the volume - to be able to backup or just view files.

Maybe using something like [FUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io/) and in my case osxfuse.

Obviously I can mount a container and exec, 
but maybe there are other ways?

Tried to ssh into the node and cd to `/home/kubernetes/containerized_mounter/rootfs/var/lib/kubelet`

But I get `cd: pods: Permission denied`

Comment: What do you mean by local drive? Linux can mount a PV to a mount point. The issue is the PV volume disk format that and this will determine if you can read the data as directories/files. Edit your question with more details on your exact environment. Docker volumes are files combined using the Union FS. These files are viewable in the host OS. I am not aware of a Docker/Container tool that will take a GCP PV, mount it and process the contents.

Comment: anything able to view data on the volume - to be able to backup or just view files

Comment: Not sure if I good understood you. Could you elaborate? Also did you saw this: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/local-ssd ?

Comment: Thanks, I am just looking for a way to see files in a PV from a local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding sharing `PersistnetDisk` between other `VM's` it was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910960/share-a-persistent-disk-between-google-compute-engine-vms). If you want to use the same PD on many nodes, it would work only in `read-only` mode.

Easiest way to check what's inside the PD is to SSH to node (like you mentioned), but it will require superuser privileges (sudo) rights.
- SSH to node

```
$ sudo su
$ cd /home/kubernetes/containerized_mounter/rootfs/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts
$ ls
```

Now you will get a few records, depends on how many PVC you have. Name of folder is the same as name you get from `kubectl get pv`.

```
$ kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM                  STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-53091548-57af-11ea-a629-42010a840131   1Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound       default/pvc-postgres   standard                42m
```

Enter to it using cd

```
$ cd <pvc_name>
```

in my case:

```
$ cd gke-gke-metrics-d24588-pvc-53091548-57af-11ea-a629-42010a840131
```

now you can list all files inside this PersistentDisk

```
...gke-gke-metrics-d24588-pvc-53091548-57af-11ea-a629-42010a840131 # ls
lost+found  text.txt
$ cat text.txt 
This is test
It's not empty
```

There is tutorial on [Github](https://gist.github.com/mollymerp/26ef43f8f72577e7133c95f9c9f893c8) where user used `sshfs` but on MacOS.

===

Alternative way to mount PD to your local machine is to use [NFS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs). However, you would need to configure it. Later you could specify mount in your `Deployment` and your local machine. 
More details can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs).

===

To create backup's you can consider [Persistent disk snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots).